Clarification on Properly Shutting Down a Boost Beast Server
I'm working with the Boost Beast advanced server example (available at Boost.org) and am using it as a basis for my own server. My understanding is that in this example, both the session and the listener are self-sustaining objects; they keep themselves alive by always attaching a shared_ptr of themselves to a callback handler. This design seems very elegant and practical as it appears to simplify error handling by allowing the structure to self-destruct when there are no pending asynchronous operations.
However, I'm unclear about how the entire system is shutdown. The code first calls ioc.stop() and then joins on the corresponding threads. I initially thought ioc.stop() would handle the cleanup of any pending handlers and associated shared_ptrs, but that does not seem to be the case. It seems more likely that any remaining handlers are destroyed by the final destruction of ioc itself, thereby cleaning up any remaining shared_ptrs.
In my server implementation, I've handled it by using a unique_ptr for the io_context and explicitly resetting it in the destructor of my server:
HTTPServer::HTTPServerImpl::~HTTPServerImpl()
{
    m_ioc->stop();

    for (auto& thread : m_iocThreads)
        thread.join();

    m_ioc.reset(); // reset the unique_ptr
}

I have a couple of questions regarding this shutdown process:
1.) Is the shutdown procedure in ~HTTPServerImpl, as adopted from the example, considered "clean," in terms of properly closing all sockets? How exactly does this happen? Through the destructors of beast::tcp_stream and tcp::acceptor when the shared_ptrs destruct? Or should I explicitly call cancel()/close() before stop() through some weak_ptr (Is this cancel/close allowed from the main thread? Is it thread-safe?)? Are all asynchronous operations aborted during m_ioc.reset(), or are some handlers still executed (e.g. timers)?
2.) What exactly does stop() do in this context? Does it simply prevent new handlers from being added, or is there more to it than that? The docu says "abandoning unfinished operations", what does that mean exactly? I can't see that this will stop anything. No timers are aborted prematurely either.

Based on my (extensive) experience with threading. I would let stop send a signal (or interrupt) to all threads waiting for I/O to stop them listening.  Then the next line will wait for all those threads to have stopped (this can take a short time). And only after that is it safe to delete the HTTPServer (since threads may access data in that object they need to be stopped before it is fully deleted)


It seems more likely that any remaining handlers are destroyed by the final destruction of ioc itself, thereby cleaning up any remaining shared_ptrs.

Indeed. stop merely "stops the world" but doesn't "get rid of history".
The destructor does.

Q1. Is the shutdown procedure in ~HTTPServerImpl, as adopted from the example, considered "clean," in terms of properly closing all sockets?

Yes. It closes all sockets implicitly because they're only kept alive by the reference count in any pending async operation (shared_from_this).

Q2. What exactly does stop() do in this context? Does it simply prevent new handlers from being added, or is there more to it than that?

It stops the scheduler. Frankly, that's an implementation detail. It functionally prevents any handler from being run and breaks any running event loops (e.g. io_context.run()).
You ask a lot of questions along the way, but I think it all boils down to these:

Or should I explicitly call cancel()/close() before stop()

I would, yes. Keep in mind you take into account some kind of timeout to avoid situations where the shutdown deadlocks itself. This would be "defense against byzantine failure" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byzantine_fault)

through some weak_ptr

That's how I usually do it. In fact you can probably search my answers using weak_ptr, cancel, session as keywords to find examples.

Is this cancel/close allowed from the main thread?

Not as long as other threads may access the IO objects.

Is it thread-safe?

Cancel has no exceptional safety guarantees, so the usual applies (e.g. https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_85_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__tcp/socket.html#boost_asio.reference.ip__tcp.socket.thread_safety)
Modernize
Here's how I'd probably write the same:
Live On Coliru
#define BOOST_ASIO_NO_DEPRECATED
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/beast.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <optional>
#include <queue>
namespace beast     = boost::beast;     // from <boost/beast.hpp>
namespace http      = beast::http;      // from <boost/beast/http.hpp>
namespace websocket = beast::websocket; // from <boost/beast/websocket.hpp>
namespace net       = boost::asio;      // from <boost/asio.hpp>
using beast::string_view;
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

namespace mime { // see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48235134/85371
    struct CiCmp {
        template <typename R1, typename R2> bool operator()(R1 const& a, R2 const& b) const {
            return boost::algorithm::ilexicographical_compare(a, b);
        }
    };

    static std::map<string_view, string_view, CiCmp> const s_ext_map{
        {".txt",  "text/plain"},
        {".htm",  "text/html"},
        {".html", "text/html"},
        {".php",  "text/html"},
        {".css",  "text/css"},
        {".js",   "application/javascript"},
        {".json", "application/json"},
        {".xml",  "application/xml"},
        {".swf",  "application/x-shockwave-flash"},
        {".flv",  "video/x-flv"},
        {".png",  "image/png"},
        {".jpe",  "image/jpeg"},
        {".jpeg", "image/jpeg"},
        {".jpg",  "image/jpeg"},
        {".gif",  "image/gif"},
        {".bmp",  "image/bmp"},
        {".ico",  "image/vnd.microsoft.icon"},
        {".tif",  "image/tiff"},
        {".tiff", "image/tiff"},
        {".svg",  "image/svg+xml"},
        {".svgz", "image/svg+xml"},
    };
} // namespace mime

static string_view mime_type(string_view n_path) {
    auto const ext = [](string_view n_path) {
        auto pos = n_path.rfind(".");
        return pos != string_view::npos ? n_path.substr(pos) : string_view{};
    };

    if (auto i = mime::s_ext_map.find(ext(n_path)); i != mime::s_ext_map.cend()) {
        return i->second;
    } else {
        return "application/text";
    }
}

// return path normalized for the platform
std::string path_cat(string_view base, string_view path) {
    if (base.empty())
        return std::string(path);
    std::string result(base);
#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(__CYGWIN__)
    char constexpr path_separator = '\\';
    if (result.back() == path_separator)
        result.resize(result.size() - 1);
    result.append(path.data(), path.size());
    for (auto& c : result)
        if (c == '/')
            c = path_separator;
#else
    char constexpr path_separator = '/';
    if (result.back() == path_separator)
        result.resize(result.size() - 1);
    result.append(path.data(), path.size());
#endif
    return result;
}

// Return a response for the given request.
template <class Body, class Allocator>
http::message_generator //
handle_request(string_view doc_root, http::request<Body, http::basic_fields<Allocator>>&& req) {
    auto const error = [&req](http::status code, std::string body) {
        http::response<http::string_body> res{code, req.version(), std::move(body)};
        res.set(http::field::server, BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING);
        res.set(http::field::content_type, "text/html");
        res.keep_alive(req.keep_alive());
        res.prepare_payload();
        return res;
    };

    if (req.method() != http::verb::get && req.method() != http::verb::head)
        return error(http::status::bad_request, "Unknown HTTP-method");

    // Request path must be absolute and not contain "..".
    if (req.target().empty() || req.target()[0] != '/' || req.target().find("..") != string_view::npos)
        return error(http::status::bad_request, "Illegal request-target");

    std::string path = path_cat(doc_root, req.target());
    if (req.target().back() == '/')
        path.append("index.html");

    // Attempt to open the file
    beast::error_code           ec;
    http::file_body::value_type body;
    body.open(path.c_str(), beast::file_mode::scan, ec);

    if (ec == beast::errc::no_such_file_or_directory)
        return error(http::status::not_found,
                     "The resource '" + std::string(req.target()) + "' was not found.");
    else if (ec)
        return error(http::status::internal_server_error, ec.message());

    if (req.method() == http::verb::head) {
        // Respond to HEAD request
        http::response<http::empty_body> res{http::status::ok, req.version()};
        res.set(http::field::server, BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING);
        res.set(http::field::content_type, mime_type(path));
        res.content_length(body.size());
        res.keep_alive(req.keep_alive());
        return res;
    } else {
        // Respond to GET request
        auto const size = body.size(); // we need it after the move

        http::response<http::file_body> res{std::piecewise_construct, std::make_tuple(std::move(body)),
                                            std::make_tuple(http::status::ok, req.version())};
        res.set(http::field::server, BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING);
        res.set(http::field::content_type, mime_type(path));
        res.content_length(size);
        res.keep_alive(req.keep_alive());
        return res;
    }
}

void fail(beast::error_code ec, char const* what) { std::cerr << what << ": " << ec.message() << "\n"; }

// Echo session
class websocket_session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<websocket_session> {
    websocket::stream<beast::tcp_stream>      ws_;
    tcp::endpoint                             ep_ = beast::get_lowest_layer(ws_).socket().remote_endpoint();
    beast::flat_buffer                        buffer_;
    std::stop_token                           token_;
    std::stop_callback<std::function<void()>> stop_ //
        {token_, [this] {
             net::post(ws_.get_executor(), [this] {
                 ws_.next_layer().cancel(); // or do_close?
             });
             ;
         }};

  public:
    explicit websocket_session(tcp::socket&& socket, std::stop_token token)
        : ws_(std::move(socket))
        , token_(std::move(token)) {
        std::cerr << "Websocket upgrade (" << ep_ << ")" << std::endl;
    }

    ~websocket_session() {
        std::cerr << "Websocket session destroyed (" << ep_ << ")" << std::endl;
    }

    template <class Body, class Allocator>
    void do_accept(http::request<Body, http::basic_fields<Allocator>> req) {
        ws_.set_option(websocket::stream_base::timeout::suggested(beast::role_type::server));

        ws_.set_option(websocket::stream_base::decorator([](websocket::response_type& res) {
            res.set(http::field::server, std::string(BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING) + " modernized-server");
        }));

        ws_.async_accept(req, beast::bind_front_handler(&websocket_session::on_accept, shared_from_this()));
    }

  private:
    void on_accept(beast::error_code ec) {
        if (ec)
            return fail(ec, "accept");
        do_read();
    }

    void do_read() {
        ws_.async_read(buffer_, beast::bind_front_handler(&websocket_session::on_read, shared_from_this()));
    }

    void on_read(beast::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
        boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);

        // This indicates that the websocket_session was closed
        if (ec == websocket::error::closed)
            return;

        if (ec)
            return fail(ec, "read");

        // Echo the message
        ws_.text(ws_.got_text());
        ws_.async_write(buffer_.data(),
                        beast::bind_front_handler(&websocket_session::on_write, shared_from_this()));
    }

    void on_write(beast::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
        boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);

        if (ec)
            return fail(ec, "write");

        // Clear the buffer
        buffer_.consume(buffer_.size());

        // Do another read
        do_read();
    }
};

// Handles an HTTP server connection
class http_session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<http_session> {
    beast::tcp_stream                         stream_;
    tcp::endpoint                             ep_ = stream_.socket().remote_endpoint();
    beast::flat_buffer                        buffer_;
    std::string                               doc_root_;
    std::stop_token                           token_;
    std::stop_callback<std::function<void()>> stop_{token_, [this] { cancel(); }};

    static constexpr size_t             queue_limit = 8; // max responses
    std::queue<http::message_generator> response_queue_;

    // allow re-init in place
    std::optional<http::request_parser<http::string_body>> parser_;

  public:
    http_session(tcp::socket&& socket, std::string doc_root, std::stop_token token)
        : stream_(std::move(socket))
        , doc_root_(std::move(doc_root))
        , token_(std::move(token)) {
        static_assert(queue_limit > 0, "queue limit must be positive");
        std::cerr << "HTTP session (" << ep_ << ")" << std::endl;
    }

    ~http_session() {
        if (stream_.socket().is_open()) // unless upgraded to websocket
            std::cerr << "HTTP session destroyed (" << ep_ << ")" << std::endl;
    }

    void start() {
        net::dispatch(stream_.get_executor(),
                      beast::bind_front_handler(&http_session::do_read, this->shared_from_this()));
    }

    void cancel() {
        net::dispatch(stream_.get_executor(), [self = shared_from_this()] { self->stream_.cancel(); });
    }

  private:
    void do_read() {
        parser_.emplace();
        parser_->body_limit(10000);
        stream_.expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(30));
        http::async_read(stream_, buffer_, *parser_,
                         beast::bind_front_handler(&http_session::on_read, shared_from_this()));
    }

    void on_read(beast::error_code ec, size_t bytes_transferred) {
        boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);

        // This means they closed the connection
        if (ec == http::error::end_of_stream)
            return do_close();

        if (ec)
            return fail(ec, "read");

        // See if it is a WebSocket Upgrade
        if (websocket::is_upgrade(parser_->get())) {
            // transfer ownership to the websocket_session
            std::make_shared<websocket_session>(stream_.release_socket(), token_)
                ->do_accept(parser_->release());
            return;
        }

        // Handle an HTTP request
        queue_write(handle_request(doc_root_, parser_->release()));

        // If we aren't at the queue limit, try to pipeline another request
        if (response_queue_.size() < queue_limit)
            do_read();
    }

    void queue_write(http::message_generator response) {
        response_queue_.push(std::move(response));

        if (response_queue_.size() == 1)
            do_write();
    }

    // The single write loop
    void do_write() {
        if (!response_queue_.empty()) {
            bool keep_alive = response_queue_.front().keep_alive();

            beast::async_write(
                stream_, std::move(response_queue_.front()),
                [this, self = shared_from_this(), keep_alive](beast::error_code ec,
                                                              size_t /*bytes_transferred*/) {
                    if (ec)
                        return fail(ec, "write");

                    if (!keep_alive) {
                        // "Connection: close" semantics
                        return do_close();
                    }

                    // Resume the read if it has been paused
                    if (response_queue_.size() == queue_limit)
                        do_read();

                    response_queue_.pop();

                    do_write();
                }

            );
        }
    }

    void do_close() {
        beast::error_code ec;
        stream_.socket().shutdown(tcp::socket::shutdown_both, ec);
        // At this point the connection is closed gracefully
    }
};

// Accepts incoming connections and launches the sessions
class listener {
    net::any_io_executor ex_;
    tcp::acceptor        acceptor_;
    std::string          doc_root_;
    std::stop_source     shutdown_;

  public:
    listener(net::any_io_executor ex, tcp::endpoint endpoint, std::string doc_root)
        : ex_(ex)
        , acceptor_(net::make_strand(ex), endpoint)
        , doc_root_(std::move(doc_root)) {
        acceptor_.set_option(net::socket_base::reuse_address(true));
        accept_loop();
    }

    void shutdown() {
        shutdown_.request_stop();
        net::dispatch(acceptor_.get_executor(), [this] { acceptor_.cancel(); });
    }

  private:

    void accept_loop() {
        // The new connection gets its own strand
        acceptor_.async_accept(net::make_strand(ex_), [this](beast::error_code ec, tcp::socket socket) {
            if (!ec)
                std::make_shared<http_session>(std::move(socket), doc_root_, shutdown_.get_token()) //
                    ->start();
            else
                fail(ec, "accept");

            if (!shutdown_.stop_requested())
                accept_loop();
        });
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // Check command line arguments.
    if (argc != 5) {
        std::cerr << "Usage: modernized-server <address> <port> <doc_root> <threads>\n"
                  << "Example:\n"
                  << "    modernized-server 0.0.0.0 8080 . 1\n";
        return 1;
    }
    auto const address  = net::ip::make_address(argv[1]);
    auto const port     = static_cast<uint16_t>(std::atoi(argv[2]));
    auto const doc_root = std::string(argv[3]);
    auto const threads  = std::max<size_t>(1, std::atoi(argv[4]));

    net::thread_pool ioc{threads};

    // Create and launch a listening port
    listener lsnr(ioc.get_executor(), tcp::endpoint{address, port}, doc_root);

    net::signal_set signals(ioc, SIGINT, SIGTERM);
    signals.async_wait([&](beast::error_code ec, int) {
        if (!ec)
            lsnr.shutdown(); // TODO add deadline with forced .stop()
    });

    ioc.join();
}

With a demo:

Salient changes:

do_close does shutdown_both instead of shutdown_send; alternative you might cancel() to stop a pending read. Otherwise do_close() will not actually cause the connection to be closed
instead of tracking sessions using std::stop_token with callbacks
added tracing of accepted/upgraded/destroyed sessions
many things simplified, notably around threading


Added a modernized version with notes, and for the really modern, here's a c++20 coro version: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eed737a1657807e6

Ok, I'll study it and then mark it as a reply later. But what strikes me immediately is that there also seems to be a deeper flaw in the boost beast itself here. I have simplified your example and if I send a longer http-request series here, there is a WRITE timeout. I have already noticed this under 3 different Linux OS and it is reproducible. ONLY when also adding stream_.expires_after(...) before the async write method, you are able to send UNLIMITED requests. This feels wrong, especially since the timeout at the read should apply to both and is constantly reset in the read?

https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bb251d267573feac - ./beast_server_example 0.0.0.0 8080 4
https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1537cffa5303fb46 - ./http_client / 10000000

Ok, as I understand it now, close() is no longer necessary because the controlled shutdown means that there are no more asynchronous operations outstanding and the io threads end by themselves. All sessions and listeners are then already destroyed here, as there is no longer a shared_ptr. You are therefore no longer dependent on the goodwill of the destruction of io_context (implicitly contained in the thread pool?).
I like the solution, but unfortunately I can't use it because I can only use C++17. Can you possibly offer an alternative with C++17?

I have no issue with that go client: http://stackoverflow-sehe.s3.amazonaws.com/5202e5a4-7105-4b78-a14f-29de89475b7a/2024-05-04 17-30-51.mp4
. If you're observing that the server will not cancel, you may be running into the race condition because your client continuously spams at queue_limit, adding if (token_.stop_requested()) return; at the top of do_read() fixes it, or you can add self->do_close() to the cancel lambda.

"there are no more asynchronous operations outstanding and the io threads end by themselves" - yes, basically. It has nothing to with the shared pointers, really, just with "work" (see also make_work_guard).

Here's a c++17 emulation of the stop tokens using Boost Signals2: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/281b9d0dc3aee50b. Interestingly, I finally saw the "write: The socket was closed due to a timeout" with this, and all I can say is it looks this is by design because you have expires_after. I would just drop it. Frankly the whole tcp_stream class never really had my interest, I'd just use tcp::socket directly.

I think it is a bug. I will open an issue for that.

@topic, I believe that your examples does not work if a client pipelines many requests, since the cancel() in the session apparently does not prevent new async operations from being triggered. As a result, the shutdown hangs as long as the client is constantly firing. Since it was canceled anyway, the session is in an "inconsistent" state anyway, right? Here is my customized variant that also takes this into account + uses a tracker (c++17). What do you think about this? And should the hanging "fix" also be added to your examples? https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/68180d9fe303618c

Possibly. Anyways, the solution using shutdow_both will work and that's also in the c++17 I posted in the last comment

Ah, I've seen, in the last example in the last comment you use cancel() AND do_close(); I'm still unsure whether you need both, but I guess double is better.

One more question, please. Can you explain what the cancel() before the do_close(=shutdown) is for? Doesn't shutdown(both) also indirectly ensure that on_read() is canceled with an error, which would cause the whole machinery to dissolve? In my tests so far I could not recognize any benefit from the cancel.

I didn't want to find out. I also feel that expressive code is worth something, but yeah it's possible that shutdown implicitly cancels. It's also possible that it will refuse subsequent operations in the relevant direcftions only. I like it explicit.
